# ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique error when running RSpec test for association creation

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I'm encountering an issue while running RSpec test cases for my Rails application. The test is related to creating associations between models. Specifically, I have a test that involves creating an account association for a user. However, when running the test, I'm getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: account { |a| a.association :account }

ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
  Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_users_on_email': INSERT INTO `dummy_test`.`users` VALUES ()
```

```
RSpec.describe V2::ContentsController, type: :controller do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers
  # byebug
  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user, email: Faker::Internet.email) }
  let(:account) { create(:account, owner: user) }
  let(:api_key) { create(:api_key, account_id: account.id, user_id: user.id) }

  before(:each) do
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!('dummy_test')
    sign_in user
  end
```

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { 'Secret123#' }
    password_confirmation { 'Secret123#' }
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    factory :owner_user do
      after(:create) do |user, _evaluator|
        FactoryBot.create(:account, owner: user)
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Add your factories to your question.

Comment: Which line of code causes the error?

Comment: factories added!

Comment: it seems that you have an index with email